# dynamic SFTP from pipeline component

Tags: adapter, sftp, biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-2016

I am trying to create a dynamic sftp from pipeline component for Biztalk 2016. I need to know the namespace which is used in context properties for the creation of sftp connection. I will be configuring the basic port, server, username, password, destination, and connection limit outside of the code and outside of the BizTalk. That is why I need to know namespace that the SFTP location would be using inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just look under `BizTalk.System` and you will find a schema called `SFTP.bts_sftp_properties` which has a namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2012/Adapter/sftp-properties`