# How does dynamically set SFTP Send Port's Connection Limit in BizTalk Orchestration?

Tags: biztalk

How does dynamically set SFTP Send Port's **Connection Limit** in BizTalk Orchestration?

I see the field in the static SFTP Send Port, but I don't know the property in the SFTP namespace in orchestration.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379159/dynamic-sftp-from-pipeline-component?rq=1

Comment: Hmm, looked through that schema, and you are right, no Connection Limit